# Why am I unable to edit Hyper-V disks for running VMs when permissions are ok

Tags: permissions, hyper-v, windows-server-2016, vhdx

We have a 4 node Hyper-V cluster running about 15 VMs. On none of them I have tested, can I inspect or edit VHDXs on running VMs.
I get a permissions error of some kind when attempting to do so:

[image: Error message]

Given that the VMs are running, the hosts obviously have access to the files. I can browse to the location of the files and see them, and I can see currently Everyone has Full Control.

What else would prevent me from editing the disk given the above permissions?

Comment: I was unaware that you could edit the disk of a running VM. Have you tried shutting down one of the VM's and trying it?

Comment: I was lead to believe with VHDX type disks this could be done online. I am not currently in a position to shutdown the VM to test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of my problem seemed to stem from the fact these VMs were being managed by WSFC (failover clustering), which prevented the Hyper-V manager from making these changes.

If I instead tried this process using failover clustering manager, I was able to expand the disk while the VM was online.